# Perl - Help reading xml string through CMD line

Tags: perl, shift

The place I work has a piece of code we use when we need to interact with Perl.  Basically we call a function and it passes through a series of strings - via the command line - into Perl as an array.  This works fine for most things.

However I now need to pass through a string of XML data.  I normally extract the items from the array using the shift keyword.  However, because there are multiple spaces within the xml string then this does not work.

I have tried writing it as such:

```
while(shift)
{
   my $temp = shift;
   $animalXML = $animalXML.$temp;

}
```

But it doesn't really deal well with the xml tags.  For example, this section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ToggleExclusion   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Is read and stored as :

```
version="1.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Does anybody know how I can deal with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a Perl problem, that's a command line quoting problem. If you quote the string properly, it'll come into the Perl script as a single ARGV item and you won't have to do any manipulation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little please.  This is the data I pass to the command line:  task.Run(perlFile + " " + data + " " + DatabaseMenu._currentDatabase.ToString());  That data in between the brackets is a single string thats passed through to the command line.  The xml part is 'data', how would I quote that properly?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not when the string is a mixture of, let me guess, ASCII and UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

You are composing a single string and passing it to `Run`, which then apparently (which language and platform is this?) feeds it to a command line interpreter (`cmd`? `/bin/sh`?) that parses that command line, interprets it as the name and arguments of a command, and invokes the command with the arguments.

The command line interpreter has its own special characters with special meanings, such as `<`, so all occurrences of such characters will need to be properly escaped or quoted using whatever method the command line interpreter supports, in order to be passed through to the command unharmed.  Furthermore, the command line interpreter will have certain expectations of the character set being used that are probably not going to hold for input strings that are all UTF-16, or worse, a mixture of UTF-16 and something else.

If you can't change the Perl script: cut out the command line interpreter, by using a multi-argument variant of `Run` that directly invokes a command with arguments.

If you can change the Perl script: do as the pros do, and make it read its input from standard input instead of from command line arguments.

Another idea is not to mix XML with non-XML so you can use a proper XML library such as [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/) to parse the input, which will take care of any further quoting/escaping issues for the XML contents.

Comment: Hi, I can change the Perlscript.  It is the Run function that I cannot change.  It is a work library that I don't have access to the source code.

Comment: I think I am just going to get around it as such:  foreach $a (0 .. $#ARGV) {
print $ARGV[$a];
}  It seems to work.  Is this okay given my limitations?

Comment: Yuck.  Well, the harm is being done in that call, it loses information.

Comment: Whether something as simple as that will work depends on how complex the data is that you try to pass.

Comment: It does work, although the database information is attached to the end of the string.  So I first need to get that using $ARGV[-1] and then pop;  What's left is the xml data that I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for `task.Run`. The problem stems from there. You are looking for a way

- either to by-pass the shell
- or to quote arguments for the shell.